# Velocity of a train

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

A train travels with a velocity that doubles every hour. In 3 hours, it has travelled 350km. What was the trains velocity in the second hour?

A. 225 km/h

B. 175 km/h

C. 150 km/h

D. 100 km/h

Answer is D. Can someone explain?

Comment: I'd say the problem isn't well phrased. Is the velocity of the train constant in each hour and then doubles instantly when the next hour begins, or does the velocity of the train increase exponentially, continuously over time such that it doubles every hour?

Comment: @Christoph - As it turns out, it doesn't really matter, because the answer is the same! (See my solution below)

Comment: It would be vary interesting to be on the train after 12 hours.

Comment: @RickDecker "Speed never killed anyone. Suddenly doubling your speed, that's what gets you." - Top Gear

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the train starts with some initial velocity $v_0$, which we assume to have units of kilometers per hour. First it travels one hour at velocity $v_0$, then one hour at velocity $2v_0$ and finally one hour at $4v_0$. Since we know the total distance traveled after 3 hours, we can find $v_0$ by solving:

$$v_0+2v_0+4v_0=350$$

So $v_0=\frac{350}{7}=50$. After one hour, the train has doubled its velocity once, so during the second hour, the train travels at $100 \frac{km}{h}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the train's velocity the first hour, $y$ in the second hour,$z$ in the third.

We have the following relations:

$x + y + z = 350$ and $2x=y$ and $4x=z$

So we have $x + 2x +4x =350 km$

$$7x=350$$

hence

$x=50$ and $y=100$

Comment: this is more or less correct but you're wrong on the unit of measurament :-)

Comment: yeah I think my answer is not rigorous but the logic is here.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting to note that, whether you assume
(i) that the velocity remains constant for any hour, or
(ii) that the velocity increases exponentially (and "continuously") such that it doubles every hour,
$\color{red}{\text{the answer is the same!}}$

Several answers for (i) have already given above. 
The solution below is for (ii).

First we note that 
$$\int2^t\; dt=\int e^{t\ln 2}\; dt=\frac {e^{t\ln 2}}{\ln 2}+c=\frac {2^t}{\ln 2}+c$$
Assume the velocity at $t=0$ is $\lambda$. As velocity doubles each hour, this means that 
$$V(t)=\lambda\cdot 2^t\qquad\text{($t$ in hours)}$$
Distance in the first three hours is $350$km (given), i.e. 
$$\begin{align}
350&=\int_0^3 V(t) dt =\lambda \int_0^3 2^t\; dt=\lambda \left[\frac {2^t}{\ln 2}\right]_0^3=\frac{7\lambda}{\ln 2}&&\cdots(1)
\end{align}$$

Average velocity during the second hour is given by
$$\begin{align}\overline{V}_2&=\frac{\text{Distance travelled}}{\text{Time taken}}=\frac {\int_1^2V(t)}1\; dt=\lambda\int_1^2 2^t\; dt=\lambda\left[\frac {2^t}{\ln 2}\right]_1^2=\frac {2\lambda}{\ln 2}&&\qquad \cdots (2) 
\end{align} $$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, 
$$\overline{V}_2=\frac 27\cdot 350=100[\text{km/h}]\quad\blacksquare$$

Comment: More generally, I think, the velocity could be any function such that $v(t + 1) = 2v(t)$ where $t$ is measured in hours.

Comment: @DavidK  - Why would that be so?

Comment: OK, maybe not _any_ function; we want the function to be integrable. Then $\int_{T+1}^{T+2} v(t)\,dt = \int_{T}^{T+1} v(t+1)\,dt = \int_{T}^{T+1} 2v(t)\,dt = 2\int_{T}^{T+1} v(t)\,dt$, and so $\int_2^3 v(t)\,dt = 2 \int_1^2 v(t)\,dt = 4 \int_0^1 v(t)\,dt$.

Comment: @DavidK - Interesting conclusion... how would it be described... piecewise exponentially proportional?

Comment: It seems to me the function would have a "periodic" nature rather than a "piecewise" nature; in fact, I think any such function could be described as the product of a periodic function and an exponential function.

Comment: Yes, but it only needs be piecewise integrable.

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be "piecewise integrable"? Gaps over which it can't be integrated are no good; how far does the train travel during those intervals? And if there are no gaps, isn't the function just "integrable" throughout? What you could have is something piecewise continuous, but it could also be continuous everywhere, for example $2^t \sin t$.

Comment: Piecewise integrable within any interval $[t,t+1]$, but there could be a discontinuity at $t, t+1$, etc.

Comment: You can have discontinuities in the _value_ of $v(t)$ wherever you want. But if the function $v(t)$ is integrable on $(t,t+1)$ and on $(t+1,t+2)$ then it is integrable on $(t,t+2)$. I don't see the sense in which such a function should be considered only "piecewise integrable" rather than simply "integrable."

Comment: That's right.  Perhaps all that is required is that $v(t+1)=2v(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the intent is to solve this using linear algebra, here are the steps
$$ x =\mbox{distance traveled in the first hour}$$
$$ y =\mbox{distance traveled in the second hour}$$
$$ z =\mbox{distance traveled in the third hour}$$
This problem is expressed mathematically as
$$x+y+z=350$$
$$2x=y$$
$$2y=z$$
Which can be rewritten as
$$x+y+z=350$$
$$2x-y+0z=0$$
$$0x+2y-z=0$$
The augmented matrix of this linear system is
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 350 \\
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]$$
$$=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 350 \\
0 & -3 & -2 & -700 \\
0 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]$$
$$=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 3 & 0 & 350 \\
0 & -3 & -2 & -700 \\
0 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]$$
$$=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 3 & 0 & 350 \\
0 & -7 & 0 & -700 \\
0 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]$$
$$=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 3 & 0 & 350 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 100 \\
0 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]$$
$$=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 50 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 100 \\
0 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]$$
$$=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 50 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 100 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 200 \\
\end{array}\right]$$
Which implies that
$$ x =50\ \mathrm{km}$$
$$ y =100\ \mathrm{km}$$
$$ z =200\ \mathrm{km}$$
Since $y$ represents the distance that the train traveled in the second hour, the answer then is $100 \frac{\mathrm{km}}{h}$.